# Is SomeClass.class considered a constant with no runtime coupling?

Tags: java, classname

Where I have the following code:

```
BasePlugin p = Manager.getPlugins(...);
```

I want to get a reference to a plugin which may not may be available.

For example, lets say I do this:

```
BasePlugin p = Manager.getPlugins("PluginApple");
```

But some time later the plugin's name is changed to "PluginPear". This will break any code which hard-coded the previous constant.

I could do this:

```
try {
    SomePlugin p = Manager.getPlugins(PluginApple.getName());
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

Which works but what if instead `Manager.getPlugins()` performed its lookup based on class names rather than strings?

For example:

```
BasePlugin p = Manager.getPlugins(PluginApple.class);

if (p != null)
   ((PluginApple)p).doSomething())
```

So here's the question: I can build a jar that knows about `PluginApple` as long as it's available for reference in the classpath. But now lets say that `PluginApple` is not available at runtime. Is the value of `PluginApple.class` provided as a constant whose value is determined when the byte code is built? Or will I get some kind of runtime exception if the class is not available?

Comment: If `PluginApple` class is not part of the classpath then you will get `ClassNotFoundError` when executing `Manager.getPlugins(PluginApple.class);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But now lets say that PluginApple is not available at runtime. Is the value of PluginApple.class provided as a constant whose value is determined when the byte code is built?

No.  It is a class literal representing an object of type `java.lang.Class`.  Evaluating the method invocation requires creating that object, which in turn requires loading the designated class.

> Or will I get some kind of runtime exception if the class is not available?

You will get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  (Nice.  There are a lot fewer ways to get an `Error` than there are to get an `Exception`)